# SQL Statement Capture from within Visual Studio 2012 or MS SQL 2012

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and MS SQL Server 2012 for a C++ application.

I understand there's a way to capture SQL statements from both programs (some sort of trace profiler) for individual tables but I've run across very few tutorials on how to do perform this, and unfortunately they tend to be a bit vague on specific steps- almost as if they assume you should already know how to do this.  Is there a way to perform this capture/trace for statements that span multiple tables?  If so, how?

Unfortunately, the code I inherited is 20K lines of spaghetti code so it makes sense to capture the resulting statement before it's sent to the DB rather than spending a few weeks stepping through it.

Comment: SQL Server Profiler from the Tools menu in SSMS.  You can filter to capture the calls from certain logins and depending on the connection string used you can also filter by application name. For more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: You nailed it.  Thank you!  I just ran a successful trace and it immediately pulled exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Profiler from the Tools menu in SSMS. You can filter to capture the calls from certain logins and depending on the connection string used you can also filter by application name. For more details msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799(v=sql.110).aspx

To make it easier to profile just the calls you are looking for, if you add: `Application Name=MyAppName;` to the connection string your app uses you can then filter in SQL Profiler by Application Name Like MyAppName.